# docker compose up from cron tab not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, cron-task

i am trying to start docker as a cron job in ubuntu server. I am using this command whice works manually but when i put it in crontab -e it doesn't seem to start the container.

```
20 03 * * * docker-compose -f /root/ib-gateway-docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

Comment: What *does* it do? You should capture the output of this command (both stdout and stderr) and inspect that for errors.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that if you're running it as user `ubuntu`, you don't have permissions to access files under root. So, it might help to add `sudo`, or change the file location, but it also might be something completely unrelated.

Comment: Aug 25 06:53:01]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /root/ib-gateway-docker/docker-compose.yml up)
Aug 25 06:53:01: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)